# How to compress cites with prefix in amsrefs

Tags: amsrefs

I'm using `amsrefs`, and I would like it to compress prefixed citations.  More exactly, I do, say,

```
\def\amsrefs@label@prefix{X}
```

But in such a case `\citelist` ceases to compress the citations.

A M(N)WE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsrefs}
\makeatletter
\def\amsrefs@label@prefix{X}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
See \citelist{\cite{1}\cite{2}\cite{3}}.

\begin{biblist}
  \bib{1}{article}{
    title={T1},
  }
  \bib{2}{article}{
    title={T2},
  }
  \bib{3}{article}{
    title={T3},
  }
\end{biblist}

\end{document}
```

Without the prefix, the citation is [1–3].  With it, it is [X1,X2,X3].  I want it to be [X1–X3].  How to achieve that?